Recovering crypto from ethereum RPC
I have found some of very old RPC credentials on ethereum. I tried to run it or try to recover the balance from it. But the hostname it had is down. If I get other RPC hostnames and same credentials will I be able to recover the balance it has?
'COIN' => [
        'hostname' => '11*.***.**.77', //hostname down
        'port' => 8545,
        'driver' => 'erc20',
        'contractToken' => '0xfa1a8***CONTRACT-ADDRESS',
        'address' => '0xb205dbc29bbae900c***Etherem-wallet-address',
        'passphrase' => '**Ee22Pass-phrase',
    ]

I looked up the wallet address in explorer and it does not have any transactions since 2018.
Thank you in advanced

Without the wallet's private key there is not much you could do.
